# FancyBox: iPAD needs DoubleClick to Advance to Next Image

Tags: jquery, ipad, fancybox

I have some galleries on http://rockcitybless.com which work *perfectly* in IE, Chrome and the desktop versions of Safari, Firefox and others.

But on **iPad** the first click (on the left or right side of the image) 
displays an arrow and only second click advances the image. I need the 
first click to advance to the next image.

I read a post talking about the same issue in Safari and the fix was 
to ensure that `<a>` tags were closed.

My `<a>` tags are closed (`</a>`) and have an unclosed `<img>` tag inside of 
it. 
The tags are generated via ajax calls (if that makes any difference).

FancyBox is otherwise PERFECT!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mobile devices, you may want to try disabling the navigation arrows and use the button helpers instead.
something like:

```
$(".fancyLink").fancybox({
 arrows: false,
 closeBtn: false,
 helpers        : { 
  title : { type : 'inside' },
  buttons   : {}
 }
});
```

of course you need to load the fancybox-buttons js and css files

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to always display navigation arrows as they are shown on the first tap and on the second will trigger changing gallery item.

Comment: Do you mean displaying navigation arrows all times and not just on hover? How do you do that in Fancybox 2?

Comment: They are hidden using css, it would be easy to check for iOS device and show them.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this when you're using modernizr:

```
.touch .fancybox-nav span { visibility:visible!important}
```

Answer (score 0):

Touch events cause issues. This definitely a bit of a hack but works well:

```
$(target).on('touchend', function(e) {
    $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem in iOS when setting the visibility to hidden. If we set this to visible and adjust the opacity instead then this should keep the same functionality.

Add this to your CSS file:

```
  .fancybox-nav span {
        visibility: visible !important;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .fancybox-nav:hover span {
        opacity: 1;
    }
```