# Next/previous item on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, fancybox

I'm using fancybox 2.0 to display photo galleries. Everything is ok on all browser, the next/previous arrows can be clicked to change pictures.

However this behaviour is quite not good on iPad: one touch is required to display arrows and a second one is required to go to the next/previous picture.

Is there a way to use the "native" way on iPad (swipe left/right) to get the expected result?
Thanks for your help.
JZ

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8236090/1055987 if that helps.