# Why won't fancybox2 display on ios if multiple galleries are on one page?

Tags: jquery, ios, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm trying to load multiple fancybox2 galleries on the same page.

They display fine in IE, FF & Chrome but on an iPad or iPhone, only the first image loads; advancing to the next image does not work.

ios 6.0.1 (the only ios I have) will not change images beyond the first slide in any of the galleries.

Interestingly, if you repeatedly tap fast enough (alternating with 2 fingers), it's possible to get the image to advance. There's obviously something wrong, though.

The problem page: http://www.kellyodom.com/weddings-and-events.html

Any ideas?  How do I debug?

Comment: Try using the `helpers` buttons instead. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8236090/1055987